# How to fetch ajax request data in cakephp 2 controller?

Tags: ajax, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to send some data from my view to my controller via ajax. How do I retrieve this data in my action?

I've tried jQuery's $.ajax and $.post methods, providing the url and data, but using $this->data, $this->request->data, $_POST, $_GET or $_REQUEST doesn't work (all return as empty arrays).

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo Router::url( array("controller" => "Progression", "action" => "submit", $user['User']['id']) ); ?>",
        type: 'post',
        data: { name: "John" }
    }).done( function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

```
function submit() {
    $this->request->allowMethod('ajax');
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $data = array();

    $data['answer'] = $this->request->data; // or any of $_POST, $_GET, etc.

    return json_encode($data);
}
```

My console always keeps printing `{"answer":[]}`. I checked the network tab of my devtools and the data is successfully listed under Form data, yet I can't seem to get hold of the data in the action.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Greg Schmidt I found out that my request indeed got redirected: first it gives me a 302, then it makes a new request without the post data and returns a 200. I just can't find what the critical difference is between the two requests (URLs look the same, no case difference or anything). Can anybody help me with that?

First request:
[image: The first request, returns a 302]

Second request:
[image: The second request, without post data and returning a 200]

Comment: Have you tried examining the network requests and responses with your browser's developer tools? Maybe there's a redirect happening somewhere and the post data is not being carried through?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thanks, that seems to be the root problem. Now I just need to find out why it redirects me. See post edits...

Comment: `allowMethod(['ajax', 'post']);`, perhaps?

Comment: If I allow all methods it still fails for some reason.

Comment: The problem must be elsewhere, then. Maybe in authentication?

Comment: I have this problem when I'm adding a new controller, or action to a controller. I'm using `AclExtras`. When I run `AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync` I no longer get 302 errors and it behaves as expected. More about this at: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html